# Using a number sequence as a row in Pascal's Triangle

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

## Background

Start with a sequence of real numbers: $x_0, x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$.

Treat this sequence as a row in Pascal's triangle and fill in the numbers below this row: that is, sum each consecutive pair of numbers in the sequence to create a new sequence, and repeat this process on each newly created sequence until only one number $y$ remains.

*Example:*

Sequence $= (5, 1, 3.2, -2)$

```
5     1     3.2   -2
   6    4.2    1.2
    10.2    5.4
       15.6
```

$y = 15.6$

Using the binomial theorem, I know that $y = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} x_i$ (and we can see that if every number in the sequence happens to be equal, then this becomes $y = 2^n * x_0$). Plugging in the above example, we get:

$
y = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} x_i
  =  \binom{3}{0} * 5 + \binom{3}{1} * 1 + \binom{3}{2} * 3.2 + \binom{3}{3} * -2
  =  1 * 5 + 3 * 1 + 3 * 3.2 + 1 * -2
  =  15.6
$

I noticed that if the sequence is constructed such that the difference between any two consecutive numbers in the sequence is the same for all pairs of consecutive numbers (that is, there exists $c$ such that, for all $j \in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$, $x_j = x_{j - 1} + c$), that:

$y = \frac{2^n}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n} x_i$, which I further simplified to $y = 2^n (x_0 + \frac{n}{2} c)$.

*Example:*

Sequence $= (6, 1, -4, -9)$

$c = -5$

$y = 2^n (x_0 + \frac{n}{2} c)  =  2^3 (6 + \frac{3}{2} * -5)  =  8 * -1.5  =  -12$

```
6     1     -4    -9
   7     -3    -13
      4     -16
        -12
```

Note that if we have $c = 0$, then this becomes $y = x_0 * 2^n$, which as I noted above can be derived from the binomial theorem.

## Question

How does this equation $y = 2^n (x_0 + \frac{n}{2} c)$ relate back to the binomial theorem? Why does it simplify so cleanly? Where does that $\frac{n}{2}$ come from?

Are there other ways to construct our sequence that also simplify in a similar way (for example, if we constructed it such that $x_j = c * x_{j-1}$, or $x_j = x_{j-1} ^ c$)?

Comment: More common is to start with a sequence $a_0,a_1,\dotsc$ and take first differences $a_1-a_0,a_2-a_1,\dotsc$ and then do it again $a_2-2a_1+a_0,a_3-2a_2-a_1,\dotsc$ and so on. Information about this process can be found by searching the web for *binomial transform*. Your transformation on $a_0,a_1,a_2,\dotsc$ is, up to sign, the binomial transform on $a_0,-a_1,a_2,-a_3,\dotsc$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah, thank you for pointing me towards difference tables and the binomial transform!

Comment: I don't know if this can help or not but $2^n$ is exactly the number of ways you can get from the last number to one of the numbers in the first row if in each move you move up-left or up-right (which is kinda relatable to the way new numbers are written in the triangle) and $x_0 + \frac{n}{2}c$ is the average of the sequence.